# Protecting VPS with fail2ban

Tags: linux, ssh, fail2ban

I have a VPS running ubuntu 20.04 that I'm trying to setup as a SSH server.

On my first try I got overrun by Chinese bots. I deleted everything and started from scratch.

I installed and setup fail2ban, currently on about 2000 banned ip.
I removed root login, setup a new random username, with a 12 char password.

**But** sometimes when i run `netstat -tpna` i still get results like this
[image]

These are again Chinese ip addresses. These 2 disappeared after a couple of seconds.

Is it something I'm missing here? Are these 2 really connected to my server ? How ?

Or is it just that I don't really understand how netstat works ?

I am indeed planning on removing password login, using just ssh keys, but after I finish setting up the VPS.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> On my first try I got overrun by Chinese bots

Regardless of IDS (fail2ban etc) it is always advisable to change port sshd listening on something else (if you don't necessarily bound on 22 for some reason).

> i still get results like this `... ESTABLISHED ...`

This can basically have 2 major reasons:

1. this IPs are not (yet) banned due to some missing rule or not fully covered "attack" vector.
   Did you check the IPs were really banned? See also first answer in [wiki :: FAQ](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-fail2ban-works).
   If there just no finding for this IPs at all in fail2ban.log (`[sshd] Found 192.0.2.1`), you may also try to set `mode = aggressive` for the jail.
    And check whether your fail2ban version or your sshd filter is not too old, e. g. [here is actual filter](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/filter.d/sshd.conf) for latest v.0.10. There is no guarantee that this filter would work with your fail2ban version, if you have also v.0.10, but other version (for example latest 0.10.6 vs. 0.10.2 on your side), so be careful updating the filter only.
2. If they are really banned by fail2ban, it may depend on its banning action (and config of the net-filter and network subsystem). Sometimes it is possible that only the new packets will be rejected or dropped, already established connections are not affected. This don't imply that the intruder is able to continue the attack.

However if the IP is banned (so `[sshd] Ban 192.0.2.1` is there), but you always see `Already banned` for this address in fail2ban.log later (and you see new attempts or even connections from this IP), then your banning action may not work properly (some errors in log after every ban, wrong port are protected, [net-filter white-listing rules](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2545#issuecomment-543347684) available, etc).

> Are these 2 really connected to my server ? How ?

The connection may remain established (also if the IP got banned) for some time, if it is not dropped (killed) or one of both side does not close it.
As already said it depends.
You can surely add some custom second action killing all the connections from IP (e. g. using `tcpkill`, `killcx`, `ss` or whatever), but it is not needed if you don't see any communication from its side (all packets are rejected, so no new attempts in log and no new connections later from this IP, etc).

Anyway if they disappeared as you said after couple of seconds (I guess firstly going in `TIME_WAIT` state), then it is a good sign. But better check it with something like:

```sh
tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd
# or for journal:
journalctl -f | grep sshd
```

so you would see what happens before and after ban of some address (for example whether it remains silent hereafter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've managed to test netstat behavior with another server.
When you execute "ssh user@server", netstat already sees the connection as "established" even if you don't input the password. So this was the misleading part for me, as I thought that "established" means that the attackers have access to my server.